# Not able to Perform Aggregation in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am pretty new to Elasticsearch and have been using it's High Level Rest Client to perform aggregation for date range. When I run the code, the query gets executed successfully but the returned object has null as an aggregation value:

This is how I am trying:

```
AggregationBuilder aggregation =
    AggregationBuilders
        .dateRange("agg")
        .field("date_created")
        .format("MM")
        .addRange(11, 12) // from 11 to 12 (excluded)

SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("index_name");
searchRequest.types(Long.toString(1234));
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder
        .query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
        .aggregation(aggregation);

SearchResponse searchResponse = this.client.search(searchRequest);
```

The searchResponse object has aggregation as null value.

But when I run aggregation query in Kibana, this is what I get

```
POST /index_name/1234/_search?size=0
{
    "aggs": {
        "range": {
            "date_range": {
                "field": "date_created",
                "format": "MM",
                "ranges": [
                    { "from": "now-0M/M" } 
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "range": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "11-*",
          "from": 1509494400000,
          "from_as_string": "11",
          "doc_count": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Can some please help me on this? I am kind of stuck for a very long time.

Adding sample data as per request:

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "index_name",
        "_type": "1234",
        "_id": "AV__ZmN6KNpjod2Y_7PE",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "category": 1234,
          "i_id": 87665,
          "v_Id": 12,
          "date_created": "2017-11-27T14:33:38.954Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "index_name",
        "_type": "1234",
        "_id": "AV_-XzlpzSX1UeitwVjd",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "category": 1234,
          "i_id": 8766,
          "v_Id": 2,
          "date_created": "2017-11-27T09:46:00.095Z"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a sample data  for the above query

Comment: You're not using the same date field in your Java code and in Kibana.

Comment: @Val In my actual code, I am using the same field in both the cases. I have updated the query for Kibana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer for my problem. After creating the aggregation object, we have to manually set it to the SearchRequest.

```
AggregationBuilder aggregation =
    AggregationBuilders
        .dateRange("agg")
        .field("date_created")
        .format("yyyy-MM")
        .addRange("2017-11", "2017-12") // from 11 to 12 (excluded)

SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("index_name");
searchRequest.types(Long.toString(1234));
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder
        .aggregation(aggregation);
```

Added line to fix the code:

```
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
SearchResponse searchResponse = this.client.search(searchRequest);
```